# r subset cell value from a column based on a match from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe with two columns `specialty` and `keywords`. I use the following code in order to extract values from column `keywords` if there is a match is found between `search terms` with any value in column `specialty`:

```
speciality <- c("Emergency medicine","Allergology","Anesthesiology","Hematology","Cardiology")
keywords <- c("emergency room OR emergency medicine OR emergency department", 
          "Allergy OR rhinitis OR asthma OR atopic eczema", 
          "Pain OR local anaesthesia OR general anaesthesia OR induced sleep", 
          "Anemia OR bleeding disorders OR hemophilia OR blood cancers", 
          "Heart OR cardiac diseases OR Cardiomyopathy OR Congenital Heart Disease OR Cardiac Arrhythmia")
sample <- data.frame(speciality, keywords)
keyspecial <- "Allergology"
subkeywords <- subset(sample$keywords, sample$speciality==keyspecial)
View(subkeywords)
```

So I am searching for `Allergology` in column `speciality`. Once I run the code I get 
`Allergy OR rhinitis OR asthma OR atopic eczema`

The issue I am facing is if I search for `allergology` instead of `Allergology`, I don't get results. Or if I just want to search with `emergency` instead of `Emergency medicine`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You just need a bit of regex - try something like `subkeywords <- subset(sample$keywords, grepl("[Aa]llerg",sample$speciality))` for the case you mention - this will pick up anything containing `Allerg` or `allerg`.

Comment: You may be right with a single search term "Allergology". But my point is that the search terms gonna change every time and therefore, the code should take care of find those terms irrespective of cases and partial match.

Comment: `grepl` will cover the partial match issue.  For the capitalisation, you could use `tolower` to convert everything to lower case.  So `subkeywords <- subset(sample$keywords, grepl(tolower(keyspecial),tolower(sample$speciality)))`.  Or you can use `ignore.case=TRUE` in `grepl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str_detect` and ignore case

```
library(tidyverse)
keyspecial <- "allergology"

sample %>% 
  filter(str_detect(speciality, fixed(keyspecial, ignore_case = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
subkeywords <- subset(sample$keywords, sample$speciality==keyspecial)
```

To this one:

```
subkeywords <- subset(sample$keywords, grepl(keyspecial, sample$speciality, ignore.case=TRUE))
```

It works because of the function `grepl`, which has the `ignore.case` parameter that can be set to `TRUE` in order to ignore case. However this one looks for incomplete matches. So when you search for *Allergology* It will also find *The Allergology* and things like that.

In order to only match full words you can use this one:

```
subkeywords <- subset(sample$keywords, tolower(sample$speciality)==tolower(keyspecial))
```

This way you will first convert both words to lowercase form before comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some string trimming like this:

```
matchList <- sapply(speciality,function(x) strsplit(tolower(x),split=" ")[[1]])
keyspecial <- "Allergology"
subkeywords <- subset(sample$keywords,sapply(matchList,function(y){any(tolower(keyspecial) %in% y)}))
View(subkeywords)
keyspecial <- "allergology"
subkeywords <- subset(sample$keywords,sapply(matchList,function(y){any(tolower(keyspecial) %in% y)}))
View(subkeywords)
```